# find_similar_region with rmagick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick

I've been using this method which helps me find an image within another image, it seemed to be working fine in linux but once I started using it in Windows it no longer finds the image I'm looking for, but it does in linux, using the same version of the gem, imagemagick and ruby